# How do I make a tabbar as in the picture using react-navigation with react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabbar, react-native-tabnavigator, react-native-tab-view

How do I make a tabbar as in the picture using react-navigation with react native?
As in the picture , How do I do circle tab menu? react-native-svg path should I use?

[image: Image Here]

**I tried this code  :**

```
export default class TabNavigatorComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.wrapper}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
                    <Text>Tab1</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
                    <Text>Tab2</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
                    <Text>Tab3</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
  }
 }
```

My style code :

```
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper:{
    flex:1,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent:'flex-end',
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor:colors.white,
},
  container:{
    flexDirection:'row',
  justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: colors.green01,
    height:50,
    width:screenInfo.width,
},
  tabContainer:{

    height:80,
    width:80,
    borderRadius:70,
    borderColor:colors.white,
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: colors.green01,
},

});
```

Comment: these might help: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/1126, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2157

Comment: thank you @sdn404 , I couldn't find the exact answer I was looking for, unfortunately, but it was still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you should read this guide from [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html)  specially tab navigation. then you can get style to it like [this library](https://github.com/timomeh/react-native-material-bottom-navigation) or others.

Comment: I did this, but my problem was I couldn't design the picture.As in the picture , How do I do circle tab menu? react-native-svg path should I use?